# H2 console is not opening in Spring boot app when the application is started from IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

I am using Spring boot version 2.1.3.RELEASE in my gradle based spring boot project. 
I added the following dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
}
```

I added the following in the application.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

But when I start the application by running the main class from IntelliJ and access the h2 console link (http://localhost:8080/h2) I get the following :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 05 09:00:24 PDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

But when I started the app from command line using `./gradlew bootRun`, then the h2 console is loading fine.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: That should be all that's required. If you start your application with `--debug`, a condition evaluation report will be logged. What do the entries related to `H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration` show?

Comment: Did you try the default path, ie. http://localhost:8080/h2/console

Comment: I noticed that when I started the app from IntelliJ it does not load the /h2 page and shows the above error page but I just started the app from command line using ```./gradlew bootRun ``` which worked and I could open the h2 console going to /h2